# Google Auth Login Fail After Period

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm having a strange issue with the Google Auth I have put into my application. It seems to work fine when I begin testing then after I have performed multiple logins/logouts I start getting the error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE. This will consistently occur and I am unable to login beyond this. If I leave it alone for a while (maybe an hour?) it will then start working again. Also, if I use a different phone it will be unaffected by the previous phones failures and will work.

I haven't been able to determine what could be the cause of this based on what I've read in the docs. Is there some kind of limit on the number of logins that can be done in a given period?

Comment: Do you have an API key for the service?

Comment: I believe so. Would that not be included in the google-services.json file?

Comment: I'm not sure about specifically for the Google auth service where the API key would live.  I'm speaking from experience with their other services such as Maps API that throttles requests if no API key is included.  In that case the API requires the key to be sent in the request URL.

Comment: Following the guides I did not require an external key to be added but I can double check. If I was missing such an item would it not fail all the time?

Comment: I think it would be very reasonable that Google would allow x number of requests in a certain time period.  For example, 50 requests per hour or something like that.  That would allow people to test it out before getting a key.